# How can i sort 3 dimensional array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

i have this 3D array

```
var array = [
     [
       {
          ipo: 10
       }
     ],
     [
       {
          ipo: 5
       }
     ],
     [
       {
          ipo: 15
       }
     ],
];
```

i want to sort by ascending and by descending.
I tried this:

```
array.sort(function(a, b) {   //ascending
 return a.ipo - b.ipo;
});
```

but doesn't works...
What do you suggest ? maybe i need to add `for loop` inside function?

Comment: do you have more elements in the inner arrays? btw, it's only 2D.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming only one element in the inner arrays, you could take this element for accessing the property

```js
var array = [[{ ipo: 10 }], [{ ipo: 5 }], [{ ipo: 15 }]];

array.sort(function(a, b) {
    return a[0].ipo - b[0].ipo;
});

console.log(array);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not work because there is an `b.ipo` does not exist. You can use `b[0].ipo` then compare it, eg:

```js
var array = [ [ { ipo: 10 } ], [ { ipo: 5 } ], [ { ipo: 15 } ], ];
array.sort(function(a, b) {
 return a[0].ipo > b[0].ipo;
}); 
console.log(array);
```